# mysql using like operation error

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database

I am executing a sql query.

my table

```
   __________________________
  |          col1            |
   ---------------------------
  | data for hello user      |
  |  data                    |
  -----------------------------
```

when i am executing query

```
Select *
from table
where col1 like '%data for hello user admin%'
```

it gives no data

My table contain data `data for hello user` but i want if a use `data for hello user admin`
it also give me same data as `data for hello user`.

Is this possible and how can i do that.

Comment: remove first percentage "col1 like'data for hello user admin%'"

Comment: but there table contain data with less length and query contain data with greater length. from table  `data for hello user ` from sql query `data for hello user admin`

Comment: Pardon? Do you want the query to return fake matches?? According to what rules?

Comment: no i am allowing user to search col1 data as user did'nt know about the data present in table so if he types more data than present in my `col1` than also it gives the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use substr to get exact length of col1 contain

```
select * form `table` where `col1` like CONCAT( SUBSTRING(  'data for hello user admin', 0, LENGTH(  `col1` ) -1 ) ,  '%' )
```

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0557 sec)

Comment: it is about you substring you can make it more small or try this one  "select * form `table` where `col1` like CONCAT( SUBSTRING(  'data for hello user admin', 0, LENGTH(  `col1` ) -5 ) ,  '%' )"

Answer (score 0):

If you want both rows, do `select * form table where col1 like 'data%'`

If you want the query to return both rows when the string is `data for hello user admin` then it is not possible, because the `LIKE` works only on one direction: from the input string to all rows, and not the other way around.

If what you want is to find the first match, then you'd need to keep removing words from the input string until you find a match:

`data for hello user admin%` --> no match

`data for hello user%` --> One match

`data for%` --> One match

`data%` --> Two matches